# How to switch environments automatically using SAS EG

Tags: sas

I was wondering if it is possible to switch environments automatically using SAS EG. i.e, I want to run part of my project in environment A, then I want SAS EG to automatically switch environment B and run the other part of the project. Thanks in advance for you help and guidance.

Comment: The last time I checked - 2 years ago - this was’t possible within EG. If you’re calling your processes externally, there may be an option. Post more details.

Comment: the processes are embedded within the EG project

Comment: What does "environment" mean?  You mean have part of the process flow run on one server and then have the remainder of a flow execute on a different server?  Why?  If you can't get EG to do what you want, you could look into SAS/CONNECT.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into SAS/Connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you cannot switch environments "on the fly" (point at different SAS metadata instances), you can launch EG with a command-line option that points to a particular environment.  Example:

```
"C:\Program Files\SAS\EnterpriseGuide\7.1\seguide.exe" /profile:"My Server"
```

See more [in this blog post](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2009/08/03/using-sas-enterprise-guide-with-different-sas-environments/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.